# Leer respuestas web para ver si contienen un texto dado

Tags: vb.net

Estoy intentando leer páginas web, por ejemplo me gustaría detectar el string "My server" en la respuesta.

He encontrado esto:

```
Dim Str As System.IO.Stream
Dim srRead As System.IO.StreamReader
Try
' make a Web request
Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/quietoputo")
Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse = req.GetResponse
StR = resp.GetResponseStream
srRead = New System.IO.StreamReader(Str)
' read all the text 
RichTextBox1.Text = srRead.ReadToEnd
Catch ex As Exception
RichTextBox1.Text = "Unable to download content"
Finally
' Close Stream and StreamReader when done
srRead.Close()
Str.Close()
End Try
```

Si entramos a la web simplemente vemos un título "My server:" seguido de otro título con la IP. Mi intención es detectar si la web que he visitado tiene el string "My server:" y guardar la IP en un textbox o variable o lo que sea.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Que problema tienes con el código que nos muestras?

Comment: Hola Pikoh! Como comento en el ejemplo, "Mi intención es detectar si la web que he visitado tiene el string "My server:" y guardar la ip en un textbox o variable o lo que sea." Y como se puede ver el código simplemente guarda la web en un richtextbox.

Con lo que me pueden dar 2 soluciones, o leer diferente la web o leer el richtextbox.

Y lógicamente no se como hacerlo por eso pregunto... :) Saludos!

Comment: Pero, el código funciona no? En ese caso, simplemente mete el texto en una variable en lugar de en un RichTextBox `Dim texto as String = srRead.ReadToEnd`  y haz una busqueda en texto: `IF texto.Contains("My Server")...`

Comment: pero al ser una web, no tengo que pasarlo a richtextbox?

Comment: No,la respuesta que te devuelve es efectivamente html,pero el html es texto, y tu en principio no quieres analizar nada mas que si contiene una cadena en concreto.

Comment: Ah vale entiendo! Muchísimas gracias Pikoh! Un saludo! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente debes meter el texto en una variable `string` en lugar de en un `RichTextBox`:

```
Dim texto as String = srRead.ReadToEnd
```

y luego hacer una búsqueda en texto usando [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
IF texto.Contains("My Server")..
```